# How can I get all Razor Page routing endpoints and filter for one with a specific attribute value

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a custom attribute I want to apply to a Razor Page like this

`@attribute [PageKey("PageKeyToSearchFor")]`

Then from another Razor Page I want to search all my Razor Pages for the one that has the key I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an `EndpointDataSource` from dependency injection which will give you access to all registered endpoints in the routing system.

For each endpoint you can then check for your attribute by using the `endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<TYourAttribute>()` method then compare against the value if `GetMetadata` was not null.

NOTE: If you are looking at Razor Page endpoints or anything else that might be dynamically compiled then the endpoint from `EndpointDataSource` might not have all the metadata you would expect.  To get the full metadata you need to use the `PageLoader` class (available from DI as well) to get the full endpoint with all it's metadata.  For example:

```csharp
var pageActionDescriptor = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<PageActionDescriptor>();

var endpointWithFullMetadata = await pageLoader.LoadAsync(pageActionDescriptor)
```