# C# Blazor server side - access page @attribute in middleware

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have custom attribute
`public class IPRestrictAttribute : Attribute`

and I use it to decorate Blazor server side page like so

```
@page "/"
@attribute [IPRestrict("127.0.0.0/24")]
...
```

and I want to read attribute in middleware

```
    public class IPRestrictMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public IPRestrictMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            await _next(context);

            var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
            var attribute = endpoint?.Metadata.OfType<IPRestrictAttribute>();

            if (attribute?.Any() ?? false) { ... }
        }
    }
```

middleware is registered in Program.cs `app.UseMiddleware<IPRestrictMiddleware>();`

But `attribute` variable in middleware is always empty. How to access @attribute from page in middleware?

Comment: Not all metadata might be available; you probably need to load them at runtime. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67579674/9080566.

Comment: PageLoader didn't seem to work neither. It gets metadata only for "/Pages/_Host.cshtml" page just like `context.GetEndpoint();` does.

Comment: The S in SPA stands for _Single_. Only the very first page will pass through your Middleware.

Comment: You're right. So my way with middleware seems wrong. But there must be a way to access page attributes. For example [Authorize] or [AllowAnonymous] are used regulary.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a way how to access attribute.

```
var pages = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace == "Solution.Pages" && t.GetCustomAttributes<IPRestrictAttribute>().Any());
var page = pages.FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetCustomAttributes<RouteAttribute>().Any(x => x.Template.Equals(context.Request.Path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
            
var attribute = page?.GetCustomAttributes<IPRestrictAttribute>();
```

I'm not saying it's optimal code but it's working. Pages variable should be outside middleware as static global...